# Is it necessary to use "numpy.float64"?

Tags: python, numpy, algebraic-data-types

i recently saw an example about "Linear regression"
where he uses while creating an array with numpy in order with  dtype = numpy.float64

```
x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4] , dtype = numpy.float64)
```

i tried without flaot64 where it returns different value rather than error
why?

Comment: `x = numpy.array([1., 2., 3., 4.] )` should do the same.  Depending on the operation, an integer array can yield different results, usually because the results are truncated to integers at one or more levels.  Providing floats as inputs when you expect float results is a good idea.

Comment: why float64 instead use just float

Comment: You need to give us a real example of this difference,   No generalities.

Answer (score 1):

What data type to use depends on the use case.

```
    x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4] , dtype = numpy.float64)
```

Here the elements of an array are of type float64 (Double precision float).

```
    x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Here the elements are of type int64 (Integer)

Comment: Is it necessary or I use float16 will it give errors

Comment: No, it wont give any errors, it is just about precision, which depends on your use case. For more details on data types in numpy please refer https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.types.html